# Is it possible to access console and localstorage from android studio?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I have an Android application with a WebView, would it be possible to know that I am saving LocalStorage of my device from Android Studio?

And another question, is it possible to run javascript code from Androi Studio like in a Chrome console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from Chrome. Open it and type `chrome://inspect` in the search bar. Then select the remote target where the app is being run.

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript code from Android studio through [Javascriptinterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface)